# Using Streams.zip method to use two streams simultaneously for LocalDate objects

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I need to stream through two lists provided to me as input and i want to compare the elements in both the lists at the same index and **return true if the element of first list is always greater than the element of second** list.I could have solved the problem using a loop,but aesthetically speaking and keeping the code readability in mind i want to use java streams.

```
 static boolean validate(List<LocalDate> endDates, List<LocalDate> startDates) {
    //check for all elements if the element in first list is greater than elements in second list.
    //return false if above condition fails.
    Streams.zip(endDate, startDates, (endDate, startDate) -> {..})
}
```

Comment: Hi Ankit Sharma, thank you for joining the community and making a first step. Could you please formulate this as a question? Currently this seems like you making a statement that you will be using streams. How can we help you?

Comment: What's that `Streams` class? The one in `java.util.stream` neither has method `zip` nor is visible outside the package.

Comment: @ernest_k sorry,i was using some internal framework which has Streams util class.Yes i am talking about java.util.stream. Is there a way i can pick elements from both the lists simultaneously and compare them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Stream.allMatch` with a one to one comparison of your list elements:

```
static boolean validate(List<LocalDate> endDates, List<LocalDate> startDates) {
    return IntStream.range(0, endDates.size())
            .allMatch(i -> endDates.get(i).isAfter(startDates.get(i)));
}
```

This of course assumes that both lists are of the same length (if `endDates` is shorter than `startDates`, you have a bug; if `startDates` is shorter, an exception will be thrown on `startDates.get(i)`)

Answer (score 0):

The current implementation of Stream API (including the newest version of Java 16) doesn't offer such method and you need to either use a third-party library, for example [StreamEx](https://github.com/amaembo/streamex) and the method [`StreamEx.zip()`](http://amaembo.github.io/streamex/javadoc/one/util/streamex/StreamEx.html) or use the [`java.util.IntStream.range`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#range-int-int-) to achieve the very same result. However, you are responsible to avoid the index overflow, though.

A minimal sample:

```
List<LocalDate> one = Arrays.asList(LocalDate.now(), LocalDate.now(), LocalDate.now());
List<LocalDate> two = Arrays.asList(LocalDate.MIN, LocalDate.MIN);

boolean allAfter = IntStream
        .range(0, Math.min(one.size(), two.size()))                 // limit the indices
        .allMatch(index -> one.get(index).isAfter(two.get(index))); // compare the dates
```